# Input pattern doesn't match completely in IE11, but in Chrome, FF

Tags: regex, html, internet-explorer-11

The following input field validates completely in Chrome and FF, but only partially in IE11.

```
<input name="bic" value="" type="text" title="BIC-Code" required
 pattern="[A-Z]{6}[A-Z2-9][A-NP-Z0-2](|[A-WY-Z0-9][A-Z0-9]{2}|X{3})"
>
```

Testing the code with a BIC with 8 characters always works in any browser. Testing it with 11 characters produces an error in IE.

Currently installed version: 11.0.9600.17959, updateversion: 11.0.22

#### Examples:

- 6 chars are valid in all Browsers: `RBOSGGSX`
- 11 chars are valid in all Browsers except IE: `GENODEF1S04`

#### Questions:

- Is there a bug in IE (probably)?
- Are there known limitations in the use of regex in IE?
- Do I make an error which Chrome and FF ignores?

The only thing Google finds is the `type='number'` "problem" with `^[0-9]*$`.

http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/common-input-element-attributes.html#the-pattern-attribute says:

> This implies that the regular expression language used for this
>   attribute is the same as that used in JavaScript, except that the
>   pattern attribute must match the entire value, not just any subset
>   (somewhat as if it implied a ^(?: at the start of the pattern and a )$
>   at the end).

Even the Javascript-Engine validates correctly in IE11:

```
new RegExp("^[A-Z]{6}[A-Z2-9][A-NP-Z0-2](|[A-WY-Z0-9][A-Z0-9]{2}|X{3})$").test("GENODEF1S04");
```

Comment: What happens if you put the "or nothing" branch last instead of first: `([A-WY-Z0-9][A-Z0-9]{2}|X{3}|)`  ... or if you drop that and use an optional group instead: `([A-WY-Z0-9][A-Z0-9]{2}|X{3})?`?

Comment: @AlanMoore Thank you so much! Apparently the "or nothing" branch must not be at the beginning and both of your alternative notations work. How can I raise your reputation and mark the question as solved?

Comment: Well, that's good to know!  I posted it as an answer so you can accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems IE11 can't handle alternation where the first branch is empty.  This:

```
(|[A-WY-Z0-9][A-Z0-9]{2}|X{3})
```

...should be equivalent to this:

```
((?:[A-WY-Z0-9][A-Z0-9]{2}|X{3})??)
```

...meaning `[A-WY-Z0-9][A-Z0-9]{2}` or `X{3}` or nothing, with "nothing" being the first (or preferred) option.

I recommend against using the "or nothing" idiom, even with the empty branch at the end (which seems to work okay in IE11).  It's not very common, and I think an optional group does a better job of communicating your intent.

Comment: I found today that if the first alteration even _accepts_ empty then the bug is triggered.  I had `(\d{0,2}(\.[0|5]?)?)|N/A|A/S` .. that is, a number with option .0 or .5 (but no other decimals), and the number is max 2 digits, but accepts _zero_ digits (so leaving the field blank is acceptable). _THAT_ first alteration -- accepting blank -- triggered the bug for me.

Comment: More generally, IE 11 requires that no two options in an alternation be able to start with the same character (for the regex in a pattern attribute).  If multiple options can start with the same character (or blank), all but the first will be ignored for that case.  (I ran into this problem with the regex `[1-9]|1[0-2]`.)